# Access Array with an Array of Indices

Tags: c#, java, arrays

I wondered, if it was possible to access a specific element of a multidimensional array using an array, rather than multiple integers.

Like for example:

```
int[,] map = sampleMap;
int[] position = { 1, 2 };

sampleObject = map[position]; // This line won't work. "cannot implicitly convert type 'int[]' to 'int'"
```

Instead of:

```
sampleObject = map[position[1], position[2]]
```

Of course, when working with only 2 dimensions, it wouldn't be much of a problem, but imagine I had many dimensions, like 10:

```
map[position[1], position[2], position[3], ..., position[10]]
```

It would be much nicer and more elegant, to just write:

```
map[position]
```

I've been looking around, but the best I found was "How to access Arrays in [insert programming language here]" or "how to access elements from [insert Array type here]" or things like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [Array.GetValue(int[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c2cf72s5.aspx) method

Comment: yup, that works:  `int[,] map = {{1,1}, {1,2}, {1,3}};
 Console.WriteLine(map.GetValue(new[] {1,1})); // 2`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a *thought*:

Assume your array contains 20 rows and 20 columns.

Lets say, you want to access the 26th element in your map (from the beginning of the map, top down left to right),

So, your coordinate function accepts 26 as a parameter, and,

```
26 / 20 = 1
26 % 20 - 1 = 5
```

translates `map[26]`  to `map[1, 5]`, returning it's value

Not too sure if this will be helpful to you,
just a thought!

Comment: True, this would work, but I still prefer the Array.GetValue(int[]) method suggested by Novakov. It's more intuitive and far easier to use, especially when working with many dimensions.