# Accessing single-dimensional array entries with index array

Tags: c#, arrays, indices

I am trying to access elements in a single-dimensional "data" array (string or double)  via another array that contains the indices I wish to extract:

```
string[] myWords = {"foo", "overflow", "bar", "stack"};
int[] indices = {3, 1};

string[] someWords = myWords[indices]; // Extract entries number three and one.
```

The last line is refused by the compiler. What I'd like to see is `someWords == {"stack", "overflow"}`.

As far as I know, this works in Matlab and Fortran, so is there any nice and elegant way to do this for arrays in C#? Lists are fine, too.

`Array.GetValue(int[])` like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003185/access-array-with-an-array-of-indices) does not work in my case, since this method is for multidimensional arrays only.`

Comment: That looks like syntax that would work in a language from a different paradigm. In C#, array operations are much more manual; the LINQ answer works (a library doing the job) or you could implement it explicitly as a loop over the values in `indices` with a manually-constructed array containing the results.

Comment: Of course I could do it manually, but I was specifically looking for an elegant one-liner.

Comment: I'm not sure "elegant one-liner" isn't an oxymoron **:)**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you can use LINQ, here is a way:

```
string[] someWords = indices.Select(index => myWords[index]).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks exactly like the thing I was looking for! Will try it as soon as I get back to the code.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is what you're asking about.

```
string[] myWords = {"foo", "overflow", "bar", "stack"};
int[] indices = {3, 1};
string[] someWords = indices.Select(x=> myWords[x]).ToArray();
```